# Verify that a new record is inserted to the database successfully

Tags: mongodb, spring-mvc

How do i verify that an object A added to the database successfully?
MongoTemplate.save() method doesn't return any value to verify its action result.
I found a way is to initiate value if A.Id before i save A to database using MongoTemplate.save() method, and the retrieve back the saved record using that Id value, but that way doesn't satisfy me. 
How do i verify that while keep the Id field generated by the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change writeconcern value.

```
 // This concern ensure the record saved to the disk.
 var wConcern = new WriteConcern { W = 1, Journal = true };

 WriteConcernResult wConcernResult;
 _repository.Update(ourTransaction, wConcern, out wConcernResult);
 if (wConcernResult == null)
 if (wConcernResult != null && wConcernResult.HasLastErrorMessage)
 {
       _logger.Error(wConcernResult.LastErrorMessage);
 }
```

At the update code you can pass the writeconcern value to save method

```
MongoTemplate.save(entity,writeconcern)
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. This WriteConcertResult is sure help in my case, though it's a bit wide in use. Also this is MongoDB specific, that's interesting. I will dig more into this WriteConcern and WriteConcernResult later. Just now i found that if i use MongoTemplate.save(A), and A saved successfully to the database then i will have A.Id matches the Id of the just-got-saved record.  According to that i can verify whether the save action is success or not.

Comment: That's true but if you want to ensure your id written on the hard disk not on memory you need set Journal = true to write concern property. Otherwise another thread can insert same data to db unless unique index not the case